# Gradle not respecting required attribute for features in the Manifest

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I work on an application that has the following feature tags in its manifest

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false"/>
```

We have just moved over to using Gradle to build our application. When I built the application and uploaded it to Google Play store I noticed that it added two new required features. After investigating the APK, the manifest does in fact get created with required set to true.

Does anyone have a way of fixing this, or a work around?

Comment: I have the same uses-feature with `android:required="false"` and for  me is working fine with the plugin version 0.8 and 0.9.

Comment: @rciovati which version of the build tools are you using?

Comment: I'll give it a go rolling back from using 19.0.3 and see if it works on earlier versions

Comment: I've found the issue. One of my libraries had required set to true for these permissions and Gradle merged that so that it was set for true in my release APK. I had to set required=false in the library's manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I have tracked down what was causing the issue. I have a library which has these same `user-feature` tags, and they have required set to `true`. It seems that when Gradle merges these files together the true overrides the `false` and the resulting Manifest has these features set as `required="true"`

[I have logged a problem with Gradle](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/manifest_merging_issue_where_a_library_has_a_required_feature), hopefully they fix it in a future version.

EDIT: @rciovati informed me that I logged this issue to the wrong project. I looked up the link he provided and found a [similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58433), although with `uses-library` instead of `uses-feature`.

Comment: The right place to fill a bug is here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: Thanks @rciovati looks like there is already an issue with the same basic problem but with uses-library instead. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58433